# Importing from another folder

Tags: file, import, src

cant get this working can anybody explain why

This is the code file in src folder that I created

```
# src/add.py

def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

This is the file in test folder that I am using which I want to use to import from the src file

```
# tests/test_addition.py
from src.add import add

def test_add():
    assert 1 + 1 == add(1, 1)
```

This is what I get

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> c:/Users/erceuih/hatch-test-2/.venv/default/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/erceuih/hatch-test-2/tests/test_addition.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    c:/Users/erceuih/hatch-test-2/.venv/default/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/erceuih/hatch-test-2/tests/test_addition.py
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`C:\Users\erceuih\hatch-test-2\src` `C:\Users\erceuih\hatch-test-2\tests`

Comment: Please share your folder hierarchy. I think that `src` and `tests` folders are at the same level. If so, you should write `from ..src.add import add`.

Comment: this is the hiearchy, still get the same error xD EDIT: edited on the question